# How to convert datetime to datetime2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am having an issue with a query currently where two fields in different tables are being used in a WHERE clause to filter data. Due to one being datetime and the other being datetime2, I am getting the

```
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error.
```

Here is the query:

```
/*| 1) SELECT - ABSENCES AND SCHEDULES |*/
------------------------------------------
    -- Retrieve data of absences
DECLARE @SADate AS DATETIME2(7)
SET @SADate = '2012-12-02'

    -- Retrieve absences that have a supply teacher and are within the current date.
SELECT SAStaffID
       ,LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS FullName
       ,SADate
       ,SSPeriod
       ,SSCourseCode
       ,SSRoom
    FROM tblOCStaffAbsent -- Join the staff schedule of the absent teacher that has a supply.
    INNER JOIN tblOCStaffSchedule S
        ON tblOCStaffAbsent.SAStaffID = S.SSStaffID
           AND @SADate BETWEEN S.SSStartDt AND S.SSEndDt
    INNER JOIN tblStaff SF
        ON SF.StaffID = SAStaffID
    INNER JOIN tblUsers U
        ON U.UserID = SF.StaffUserID
    WHERE SASupplyID IS NOT NULL
        AND SADate = @SADate

--------------------------------
/*| 2) SELECT - SUPERVISIONS |*/
--------------------------------
    --Union the supervisions
UNION ALL
SELECT SSupStaffID
       ,SupervisionDt
       ,CASE WHEN SSupPeriodHalf IS NOT NULL THEN SSupPeriod + '-' + SSupPeriodHalf
             ELSE SSupPeriod
        END AS FullPeriod
       ,'(SP) ' + SSupLocation
       ,NULL AS SSupRoom
       ,SSupMIDent
    FROM tblOCStaffSupervisions
    WHERE SupervisionDt = @SADate
```

SADate is the datetime field within tblOCStaffAbsent and SupervisionDt is the datetime2 field within tblOCStaffSupervisions.

Comment: Convert the dates to strings for the comparisons?

Comment: Can't you use @SADAte as just Datetime?

Comment: What datatypes are SSStartDt and SSEndDt?

Comment: Also since you only care about the date part. I would just use `DATE`

Comment: SSStartDt and SSEndDt are both DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for SupervisionDt  which is coming from tblOCStaffSupervisions table may be of DateTime Datatype. The @SADate = '2012-12-02' is a string. @SADate should be set in DateTime Datatype.

Comment: Yeah. this post is somehow funny as he says "due to one being datetime, the other datetime2" and the error clearly says: there is a string involved, dude ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at your error message, it is not problem of comparing `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2` which can be done by sql server without any problems.

You have something stored as string but you are trying to convert it to `DATETIME2`.

To convert to `DATETIME2` is done like other converts `CONVERT (DATETIME2, MyDatetimeField)`

just know that `DATETIME2` has higher precision than `DATETIME`. Your data will not change, only new information added with higher precision will use it.

Look at the following example. Both rows will produce same result.

```
DECLARE @Datetime DATETIME = '03/21/2014 15:23:34.444'

SELECT @Datetime
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, @Datetime)
```

but in the following case

```
DECLARE @datetime2 DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT @datetime2
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @datetime2)
```

first select will produce higher precision point than second one